# Spring context in N-Tier web application with Java config

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-data

We are building a Web project which uses the below Java stack. Its uses n-tier with data/business/service/web/client layers.

```
Data layer - Java, JPA, Spring-data-JPA
Business layer - Java
Service layer - Java, Apache CXF (REST/SOAP) Webservices

Client layer - AngularJS, Bootstrap
```

I am trying to figure out how to pass the spring context between these n-tiers. 
I am also trying to use Java configurations instead of XML, so quite confused.

In my earlier projects we create the spring context in the web layer with XML configuration.

I tried to follow this tutorial http://source.lishman.com/project/689#card/5509/file/19177

I am able to have a working data layer as standalone. But not sure how to inject the Repositories in the Business layer ??

The below trial works, but only after duplicating the below configuration in Business layer too which I have already defined/configured in the data layer

```
@Import(value = { DataSourceConfig.class, JpaConfig.class, RepositoryConfig.class })
```

**Business layer**

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = { DataSourceConfig.class, JpaConfig.class, RepositoryConfig.class })
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Autowired
    AirlineBusiness airlineBusiness;

    @Bean
    public AirlineBusiness getAirlineBusiness() {
        return new AirlineBusinessImpl();
    }
}
```

**Business interface**

```
@Service
public interface AirlineBusiness extends Serializable {

    public List<Airline> findAll();
}
```

**Business implementation**

```
    @Service
    public class AirlineBusinessImpl implements AirlineBusiness {

    @Autowired
    private AirlineRepository airlineRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Airline> findAll() {
        return airlineRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a separate configuration class for each layer. In each configuration class import the config class from layer below (it works transitively):

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = { DataSourceConfig.class, JpaConfig.class, RepositoryConfig.class })
public class DataConfig {

}

@Configuration
@Import(value = { DataConfig.class })
public class ServiceConfig {
}
```